# Why my canvas is drawing nothing instead of a point?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android and I want to draw points on top of my view using a canvas, but when my OnDrawListener is hit, nothing is drawn on my view and I can't figure out why.

```
new OnDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayerDrawn(Canvas canvas, float pageWidth, float pageHeight, int displayedPage) {
                canvas.drawPoint(pageHeight /2, pageHeight /2, paint);
                view.draw(canvas);
            }
        }
```

Here's how I setup my paint :

```
   paint.setColor(Color.RED);
   paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
   paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
```

Thank you.

**UPDATE :**

Here you can find my full class :

https://pastebin.com/ehB5NamS

Comment: what are your pageHeight and pageWidth values?

Comment: Paint style may need to be `STROKE`

Comment: @waqaslam my page height and width value are the height and the width of the view

Comment: @PPartisan thank you for your but it didn't change anything

Comment: can you log the values to confirm that they are not 0?

Comment: @waqaslam i log the value and i confirm you that they are not 0.

Comment: Can we have a little bit more code? Its hard to tell what could be going wrong with just this. What is your OnDrawListener, is it getting called at the right time? Is the view your rendering to set to the correct Z value, i.e. not covered by another view

Comment: @JakeWade i update my post